# Appending datetime to a list

Tags: python, list, datetime

See the code below :

```
import datetime
data =[]
dt = datetime.datetime.today()
print(dt)
for i in range(60):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes = i)
    dtnew = dt + delta
    data.append(dtnew)
 print(data)
```

This is what data looks like after running the code:

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 27, 23, 8, 18, 897419),....]
```

I should get this instead :

```
[2021-10-27 23:08:18.897419,....]
```

Any help?

Comment: when you print a list it will print out the `repr` of its items (calls `__repr__`), if you were to iterate over the list and print each element individually or do sth like `print(data[0])`, then you would perhaps see that because then it would do an implicit conversion to string which calls the `__str__` method and prints it out in a user-friendly format

Comment: cast it to string: `data.append(str(dtnew))`

Comment: What you say you 'should' get isn't an actual representation of data in Python. Do you mean you want a list of strings with formatted datetime? What you say you're getting is an actual list of datetime, that's just how the datetime looks as a representation, you can format it when printing, as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import datetime
data =[]
dt = datetime.datetime.today()
print(dt)
for i in range(60):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes = i)
    dtnew = dt + delta
    data.append(str(dtnew))
print(data)
```